# how to move back to the navigator to home page

Tags: react-native, navigator

Hai i am using navigator in react native, i wrote navigator mapping in home screen like this

```
LeftButton(route, navigator, index, navState){
    if(index > 0){
      return(
        <TouchableHighlight style={{marginTop: 10}}>
        <Text style={styles.arrow}>{arrow}</Text>
        </TouchableHighlight>
        )
    }else{
      return null
    }
  },
```

after three screens, when i click on back i need to move screen to home but here is showing before screen even though i wrote like this navigator.push() in before screen

```
this.props.navigator.push({
      component: xxxx,
      title: 'xxxx',
      onLeftButtonPress:()=>{
        this.props.navigator.popToTop();
      }
    });
```

Any one give me suggestions that how to resolve this, any help much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

when i wrote like this my code is working

```
LeftButton(route, navigator, index, navState){
    if(index > 0){
      return(
        <TouchableHighlight style={{marginTop: 10}} onPress={() =>{
          if(route.name == 'xxx'){
            navigator.popToTop();
          }else if(index > 0){
            navigator.pop();
          }
        }}>
        <Text style={styles.arrow}>{arrow}</Text>
        </TouchableHighlight>
        )
    }else{
      return null
    }
```

In navigator.push i wrote like this

```
this.props.navigator.push({
      name:'xxx',
      component: xxx,
    });
```